# Converting C pointer to Java

Tags: java, c, pointers, n-queens

I've got the assignment to create a very fast nqueens program. So far, Bruteforce algorithm and Backtrack are working, but I've found a C program which seems to be faster. Now I've tried to convert it from C to Java, however I'm unable to convert the pointers, as I'm not understanding what's happening with pointers.
These are the lines that have to be converted:

Edit: I've updated the conversions to what I've understood:

```
final int[] aStack = new int[MAX_BOARDSIZE * 2];
int bitfield; //That's what I've got so far


//Conversion 1:
register int* pnStack;       -> int pnStack;

//Conversion 2:
pnStack = aStack + 1;        -> pnStack = 1;

//Conversion 3:
pnStack = aStack + 1;        -> pnStack = 1;
*pnStack++ = 0;              -> aStack[pnStack++] = 0;

//Conversion 4:
bitfield = *--pnStack;       -> bitfield = aStack[--pnStack];

//Conversion 5:
*pnStack++ = bitfield;       -> aStack[pnStack++] = bitfield;

//Conversion 7:
pnStack == aStack            -> pnStack == aStack[0] ???????
```

A solution would be nice, but I'll try to find it myself if you can explain me what's going on here. Pointers are the reason I never actually learned c and c++.

Regards,
Dennis Fischer

Comment: Instead of pointer, use an `int` index.

Comment: I've read about that, but I have no idea what I've got to do then :). Assume pnStack is of type int: pnStack = aStack +1; what's the result saved in pnStack now?

Comment: No, you want nIndex = 1 to correspond to pnStack = aStack + 1, surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside an array, interpret a pointer just as you would use an index inside the array.

The `*` means the value in the current position of the index.

So

```
pnStack = aStack;  <-- int pnStack = 0;
pnStack++;         <-- pnStack++;
bitfield = *pnStack <-- bitfield = aStack[pnStack];
bitfield = *--pnStack <-- bitfield = aStack[--pnStack]; (first decrement index, then retrieve the value)
```

Comment: Probably less confusing to use nStack or something for the index, given it's not a pointer.

Comment: @NicholasWilson oh, right side was intended to be Java so no worries about pointers :-)

Comment: This looks good so far. However, the application is still not working as intended. Could you explain what the comparison (conversion 6) results in?

Comment: Which conversion 6??? If it is conversion 7, it would be akin to `pnStack==0` (the pointer is at the beginning of the array. Think that in C, the "array variable" in reality is a pointer to its beginning.

Comment: Yeah sorry, wrong number, was talking about conversion 7. Thank you for the help. The application is working and insanely fast compared to some other solutions. (n=15, ~ 1,8 seconds).